# M2e tool error for EClipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

Downloaded Eclipse J2EE Kepler now and wanted to install the Maven plugin from Market place.
[image]

But I keep getting this error in the picture:

[image]

So this plugin not working anymore? Is there any other recommended plugin to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [m2e-wtp site](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) you'll find that this feature is installed by default in the **Eclipse Kepler** distribution. So it's not removed, but just already included in the installation. Moreover, they (finally) upgraded it from incubation to 1.0 version. Enjoy it!

> m2e-wtp graduated from the Eclipse incubator to reach version 1.0.0. Moreover, m2e-wtp and m2e are now included in the Eclipse Java EE distribution by default. m2e-wtp 1.0.0 adds Java EE 7 support in Kepler and a few other new cool features.

Answer (score 1):

This error means it is already installed in your IDE.
IF any updates are released by M2E tools then it can be updated like you did or if you click on 'Check for Updates'.

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: efff this EClipse! I hate it ! it doesn't even show a decent message of "already installed"  damn !